# При переходах на другие активити выключается фоновая музыка андроид

Tags: android

Играет фоновая мелодия во всем приложении, не могу понять как сделать чтоб при нажатии Home музыка останавливалась, но в тоже время при переходах на другие активити не выключалась фоновая.Первую часть сделал, но теперь при любом нажатии выключается фон. музыка в андроид прилоложении.

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
Button play_btn, alphabet_btn, rate_btn;
private boolean isNeedStopMusic = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //добавление в бд
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.addLink(new Link(1, "R.drawable.watermelon"));


    initView();

    final Animation animScalePlay = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mycombo);
    play_btn.setAnimation(animScalePlay);
    play_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(animScalePlay);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            isNeedStopMusic = false;
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    final Animation animScaleAlphabet = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mycombo);
    alphabet_btn.setAnimation(animScaleAlphabet);
    alphabet_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(animScaleAlphabet);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class);
            isNeedStopMusic = false;
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    final Animation animScaleRate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mycombo);
    rate_btn.setAnimation(animScaleRate);
    rate_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(animScaleRate);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
            isNeedStopMusic = false;
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void initView() {
    play_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    alphabet_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alphabet_btn);
    rate_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate_btn);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    MusicManager.getInstance().stopPlay();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    MusicManager.getInstance().startPlay(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isNeedStopMusic) {
        MusicManager.getInstance().stopPlay();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    returnTrue();
    super.onResume();
}

public Boolean returnTrue() {
    return true;
}
```

}

---

public class MusicManager {

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Tag";
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private AudioManager audioManager;
private static MusicManager instance;

public static MusicManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MusicManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

private MusicManager() {
}

public void startPlay(Context context) {
   //if (audioManager == null && mediaPlayer == null) {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 10, 0);
    }
//}

public void stopPlay() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
```

}

Comment: `returnTrue();`!? - шедевр))). Я имел ввиду вернуть полю значение `isNeedStopMusic = true;` Когда останавливается - при переходе на другую активность или обратно, в других активностях есть управление воспроизведением, такая же проверка? Как-то сомневаюсь насчёт синглтона - `MusicManager` лучше переделать на сервис

Comment: Да действительно шедевр))  Добавил управление воспроизведением  в новые активити, но результат не изменился(

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так: добавить поле, которое будет отражать переходим мы на другую активность или просто сворачиваемся.

```
private boolean isNeedStopMusic = true;
```

Когда запускаем другую активность меняем:

```
   isNeedStopMusic = false;
   startActivity(...);
```

В `onPause` проверяем:

```
if (isNeedStopMusic) {
    // останавливаем воспроизведение
}
```

В `onResume()` возвращаем значение `true`, что бы всё работало при переходах туда-сюда-обратно:

```
isNeedStopMusic = true;
```

Comment: Сворачивание отрабатывает отлично, но при переходе на другое активити музыка стопается, не получилось

Comment: Тогда код свой показывайте. Надеюсь плеер у Вас в сервисе?

Comment: Добавил код выше